# Pointer losing reference to previous node C++

Tags: c++, nodes

I was writing a program to learn doubly linked lists. The problem I can't seem to debug is that the debugger gives me a write access violation and states that either the prevNode->next or nextNode->prev are pointing to a null. This happens as soon as you try to delete a node from nth position. I have removed some parts of the code for this post to make it shorter and easier to read, so some variables may seem unused.

The part that the debugger usually stops at is the last line before you delete the node:

```
nextNode = nodePtr->next;
prevNode = nodePtr->prev;
nextNode->prev = prevNode;
prevNode->next = nextNode;
delete(nodePtr);
```

I know for deleting nodes in the beginning and end of a list will require different code (if statement) to make sure prevNode->next and nextNode->prev are not set to a node that does not exist. The problem is that it's giving me those errors even when I'm trying to delete a node that isn't in the beginning or end of a list.

Any help or a push in the right direction would be much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    struct ListNode {
        int value;
        ListNode *next;
        ListNode *prev;
    };

    ListNode *head = nullptr;
    ListNode *newNode = nullptr;
    ListNode *nodePtr = nullptr;
    ListNode *prevPtr = nullptr;
    ListNode *nextNode = nullptr;
    ListNode *prevNode = nullptr;

    char ch = 'q';
    int val;
    int pos;

    do
    {
        cout << "h-delete from position" << endl;
        cout << "i-insert" << endl;
        cout << "p-print" << endl;
        cout << "q-quit" << endl;

        cin >> ch;

        switch (ch) {

        case 'i':

            cout << "inserting ... \n";
            cout << "Enter an integer: ";
            cin >> val;

            newNode = new ListNode;
            newNode->value = val;
            newNode->next = nullptr;

            if (head == nullptr) {
                head = newNode;
            }
            else {
                nodePtr = head;
                prevPtr = nullptr;

                while (nodePtr != nullptr && nodePtr->value < newNode->value) {
                    prevPtr = nodePtr;
                    nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
                }
                if (prevPtr == nullptr) {
                    head = newNode;
                    newNode->next = nodePtr;
                }
                else {
                    prevPtr->next = newNode;
                    newNode->next = nodePtr;
                }

            }
            break;

        case 'p':

            cout << "printing ... \n";
            nodePtr = head;
            while (nodePtr != nullptr) {
                cout << "elem: " << nodePtr->value << endl;
                nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
            }
            break;

        case 'h':
            //FIX
            int findVal;
            cin >> findVal;


            nodePtr = head;
            while (nodePtr->value != findVal) {
                nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
            }
            nextNode = nodePtr->next;
            prevNode = nodePtr->prev;
            nextNode->prev = prevNode;
            prevNode->next = nextNode;
            delete(nodePtr);

            break;

        case 'q':

            cout << "quitting ... \n";
            nodePtr = head;
            while (nodePtr != nullptr) {
                nextNode = nodePtr->next;
                cout << "deleting ... " << nodePtr->value << endl;
                delete nodePtr;
                nodePtr = nextNode;
            }

            break;

        default:
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Invalid character -- Please try again!" << endl;
            break;
        }

    } while (ch != 'q');


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please enclose your list in a class, it will make it much easier for both you to think about your code, and us to see what's going on.

Comment: @spectras I am still learning pointers and the basics of C++. I enclosed everything in main because it is easier for me while starting to learn the language. Making classes at this point will only confuse me more and potentially cause more errors.

Comment: Good on you for using the debugger. It's a great place to start. But... Quite often where the debugger stops is not where the actual bug was. It's where the data broken by the bug finally has an impact. One thing that really helps when debugging a linked list is to draw the list out on a piece of paper and follow the instructions you coded. When you find yourself instructed to do something silly, change the code to do what looks like a more-reasonable option.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for clarifying, that helps me understand the debugger better. I was going crazy trying to figure out why it kept breaking on that specific line. Who knew I messed up the program way before it reached that code haha. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will fail:

```
prevNode = nodePtr->prev;
.....
prevNode->next = nextNode;
```

because you don't give `prev` a value when you insert a node. So `prevNode` will always be `nullptr`

Stepping through line by line in the debugger will help you find these type of bugs.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that I wasn't pointing each newly created node to the previous node, only to the next. I added a pointer from each new node to the previous one and the program functions as it should. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well in `h` case, if you enter a value that does not exist, you would try to use the object at null address.

Also, if you delete the first node (the head), it won't get updated so any other operation after that what can fails as you use a destroyed object and this is undefined behavior.

Comment: It's bit worse than that. If the item is the last in the list, `nextNode = nodePtr->next;` sets `nextNode` to null, dooming `nextNode->prev = prevNode;`.

Comment: Well, there are many mistake in that code... I have spotted 2 and then stop searching.